# Does "should I have" mean "may I have" in this question?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Is this grammatically wrong?

> Should I have to come to road?

Doesn't it make the meaning like:

> May I have to come to road?

I wanted to say, "May I have to come to road? but instead of that I asked, "Should I have to come to road?" Is this wrong?

I meant: "Should I have to come to road to pick you up?"

Comment: @Tobey I think it depends on what you mean. If you ask for someone's permission then you should go with ``May``. If you expect advise, then you would go with ``Should``.

Comment: The bigger problem is that "come to road" is not idiomatic and I have no idea what you are trying to say with "come to road".  Perhaps you mean "visit the street where you live" or something like that.